# Apps to manage/host data sets

Tags: dataset, optimization

I'm looking for the best solution to manage and host datasets for journalistic pursuits. I am assessing https://www.documentcloud.org and http://datahub.io/.

Can anyone explain the differences between them, or recommend a superior solution?

Comment: I think recommendations, and for web-services, are mostly off-topic, even though this does concern hosting data.

Comment: I was marginally aware of that though I find it perhaps a tad perverse. Where does one draw the line between the relevance of finding a suitable function, programming pattern, library, framework, or an app/web-service? Any of these may serve to solve data science issues, albeit at different resolutions.

Comment: The "best" depends very much on your application and your data. Without you expanding on that, this Q will just become a list of "Howabout datafoo.io?". Even with that expansion, its still probably too much opinion.